# NighmareJS Looping Actions In A Promise Doesn't Wait Results

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, nightmare

I'm new to promises. I just started using them so that I could get results from a remote API and make use of them in my NightmareJS code. The request works great. The problem comes with my Nightmare code. I'm using the `vo` library with Nightmare. Normally I put `yield` in front of my Nightmare calls. Within the request's `.then()`, I can't use `yield`. My Nightmare calls are still working but as soon as I put them in a loop, the loop iterates over all the elements really fast without waiting for them to finish. Below is a `forEach` loop. I also tried a `for` loop.

```
let keyword = 'horror games';
let kwOptions = {
    qs: {
        query: keyword,
    },
    url: "https://api.example.com/",
    json: true
};
rp(kwOptions)
    .then(function(relKeywords){
        console.log(relKeywords[1]);
        relKeywords[1].forEach(function (element) {
            console.log('searching for: ' + element);
            nightmare.evaluate(function() {
                document.querySelector('input[cloom-label="query"]').setAttribute('value', ''); // Clear search box
            });
            nightmare.type('input[cloom-label="query"]', ' ' + element + '\u000d');
            nightmare.click('span._5d a');
            nightmare.wait(5000)
        });
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log("Couldn't get keywords: "+err);
    });
```

There must be some other pattern I can use so that I can use `yield` or some other way to fix Nightmare in a loop.

Comment: I just updated the answer, in my answer I did things in parallel. For each item in relKeywords[1] I evaluate, type, click and wait at the same time. The new answer will evaluate, type, click and wait, then when that's done it will evaluate, click and wait ... Not sure if it works because I have no way of testing, it will error when relKeywords[1] is an empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the following work? It should according to the [documentation](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#examples).

```
const processValuesSerial = (v,process) => { 
  if(v === undefined){return Promise.resolve("nothing to do"); }
  if(v.length === undefined){return Promise.resolve("nothing to do"); }  
  if(v.length === 0){return Promise.resolve("nothing to do"); }
  if(v.length === 1){return process(Promise.resolve(v[0]),v[0]); }
  return v
    .map(x => Promise.resolve(x))
    .reduce(process)
    .then(//bug fix: last item was not processed
      x=>
        process(
          Promise.resolve(x)
          ,Promise.resolve(v.slice(-1))
        )
    )
}
let keyword = 'horror games';
let kwOptions = {
    qs: {
        query: keyword,
    },
    url: "https://api.example.com/",
    json: true
};
rp(kwOptions)
.then(function(relKeywords){
  return processValuesSerial(
    relKeywords[1]
    ,(acc, element) =>
      acc
      .then(x => {
        console.log('searching for: ' + x);
        //return promise like item from nightmare
        return nightmare.evaluate(function() {
            document.querySelector('input[cloom-label="query"]').setAttribute('value', ''); // Clear search box
        })
        .type('input[cloom-label="query"]', ' ' + x + '\u000d')
        .click('span._5d a')
        .wait(5000);
      })
      .then(x => element)
  );
})
.catch(function(err){
  console.log("Couldn't get keywords: "+err);
});
```

Tips on debugging:

Start node with the debug and break flags:

```
node --inspect --debug-brk ./myscript.js
```

Open a new version of google Chrome and navigate to `about:inspect`

This window contains a link called `Open dedicated DevTools for Node`, click this link. When you start and stop your node process the debugger will automatically re connect.

When you break on error you can see where something went wrong.

**[update]**

With the following code you can play with the promises, there are 2 ways to start processing some asynchronous functions:

1. Start all of them at once
2. Start the first, wait for it to finish, then start the next

Some comments are added in the code, you can run this code in your browsers devtools in the console tab

```
//for each item in array v run process 
//  but only run the next item in v when the first item is resolved
var processValuesSerial = (v,process) => {
  //checking valid imput
  if(v === undefined){return Promise.resolve("nothing to do"); }
  if(v.length === undefined){return Promise.resolve("nothing to do"); }
  if(v.length === 0){return Promise.resolve("nothing to do"); }
  //only one item, no need to reduce
  if(v.length === 1){return process(Promise.resolve(v[0]),v[0]); }
  //at least 2 items in v, process them
  return v
    .map(x => Promise.resolve(x))
    .reduce(process)
    //last item will not be passed to process function in reduce
    //  manually execute the last process function on this item
    .then(
      x=>
        process(
          Promise.resolve(x)
          ,Promise.resolve(v.slice(-1))
        )
    )
}
//functions that do something
var logValue =
  (value,message) =>
    //log value and return it
    console.log(message,value) || value
//asynchronous function
var waitFor = 
  (howLong,returnValue) =>
    //returning a promise that resolves after waiting for "howLong"
    new Promise(
      (resolve,reject)=>
        setTimeout(x => resolve(returnValue),howLong)
    )
;


//for each value I would like to do something asynchronous.
//  for example
var values = [1,2,3,4,5];

/**
 * Problem with promises is that they start immediately so the 
 * following example will start 1,2,3,4,5 imediately and then
 * what we want is do(1).then(do(2)).then(do(3))
 */
Promise.all(
  values.map(
    x =>
      Promise.resolve(x)
      .then(
        x => logValue(x,"+++++At the same time Starting:")
      )
      .then(
        x => waitFor(x*500,x)
      )
      .then(
        x => logValue(x,"+++++At the same time Finished:")
      )
  )
)
.then(x => console.log("finished promises at the same time"))

//the following will not start everything at the same time
//   it will do(1).then(do(2)).then(do(3))
processValuesSerial(
  values
  //reducer function, acc is current value as a promise
  //  item is the next value as a promise
  ,(acc,item)=>
    //acc is a promise that resolves to "item" (=1 then 2 then 3 then 4 then 5)
    //  the first time it is 1, the second time it is whatever we return here
    //  we return a promise
    acc.then(
      //acc is resolved so we should have a value of 1, then 2 ...
      //  if we return the right value
      x=>logValue(x,"XXXXX In serie Starting:")
    )
    .then(
      //return a promise that waits
      x=>waitFor(x*500,x)
    )
    .then(
      x=>logValue(x,"XXXXX In serie Finished:")
    )
    //return next item
    .then(x=>item)
)
"OOOOOO Finished running synchronous code"
```

Comment: The first solution your posted looks like it's working okay. I will use this new method you've posted in my code too if it works to better my methods. Was there something wrong with the first one you posted?

Comment: @xendi The first one still does everything at the same time. This version should do each action after the other.

Comment: Says: `Couldn't get keywords: ReferenceError: x is not defined`

Comment: @xendi I had a typo in the original. changed it. This only works if you use node that supports native promises and arrow functions (should work unless you use a really old node version). The array of values has to be at least 2 elements long or it won't work. Trying to figure out how to deal with that

Comment: You sure you fixed it? I'm getting the same error. I was using Bluebird but I commented it out.

Comment: @xendi My code is using native promises, what does `node --version` say?

Comment: @xendi I updated my answer with new code (refactored processing values to serial promises to a function). and at the end are some debugging tips. Please let me know if you still have a problem and at what line in the code.

Comment: Using version 8.6.0.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here. Again I see a similar message `Couldn't get keywords: ReferenceError: values is not defined`. I tried to run the debugger but it's not outputting anything. Maybe something to do with the fact that it's using Electron?

Comment: I also tried using the debugger in WebStorm but it doesn't show anything in the debug pane when I run it. Just says it's connected.

Comment: @xendi the error was in processValuesSerial, values.map should have been `v.map`  I can't run the code but if you can't get your code in chrome dev tools running it would make it very difficult for you. What version of chrome are you using and what version of node?

Comment: It works. I must have made some typo before. Thanks for that. If you wind up having time, do you think you could comment the code at each step so that I can better understand what's going on and why all this was necessary?

Comment: Promises are supposed to make everything easier but working with Nightmare and promises has become a nightmare!

Comment: @xendi I added some example code with comments, also fixed a bug since I can run the example code and not only know how it would work in theory I found a bug.